# Dynamic date options for the next 12 months

Tags: php, forms, date, datepicker, dynamic-data

I have really been trying hard to achieve the following:

```
<option value="2011-11"><? echo $month[11]?> '11</option>
<option value="2011-12"><? echo $month[12]?> '11</option>
<option value="2012-1"><? echo $month[1]?> '12</option>
<option value="2012-2"><? echo $month[2]?> '12</option>
```

Where the following are dynamic according to today's date:

```
<option value="YYYY-m"><? echo $month[12]?> 'yy</option>
```

and repeating the process for the following 12 months ahead of today.

I made some progress with my rudimentary knowledge of PHP, I have admitted I need help from those more knowledgeable than myself!

It does look simple and I often look at stackoverflow to solve things though on this occasion I have spent far too much time and made too little progress.

Can anyone give me a hand to this seemingly simple challenge!?

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2):

Commenting for anybody who finds question.

The accepted answer is wrong. See here:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php#107331

use this instead:

```
<?php
for($i=0;$i<=12;$i++)
{
    $time = strtotime("first day of +". $i." months");
    print '<option value="'. date("Y-m", $time)  .'">'.date("Y-m",$time).'</option>';
}
?>
```

The fix being "first day of"

Comment: Nice work pointing out "first day of". I've been using PHP daily for over 10 years and strtotime() quite frequently for it's power and flexibility. This is the first time I've seen that used.

Answer (score 1):

This snippet is proof of concept achieving exactly what you want.

```
for($i=0;$i<=12;$i++)
{
    $time = strtotime("today + ". $i." months");

    print '<option value="'. date("Y-m", $time)  .'">'.date("Y-m",$time).'</option>';
}
```

If you want to print the name of the month in your specific language, you should take a look at [setlocale](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php) and just use the `F` parameter in [date](http://php.net/date)

Comment: You can use `mktime` over `strtotime` for efficiency and predictability of its outcome.

Comment: this method takes change of year into account, that a little more challenging with mktime.

Comment: Thanks Jan!!! I can beleive how easy that was, learning PHP is challenging though when things work it's so cool! In the end the setlocale command did'nt work so I just used an array with the month names in spanish and printed them like that! Thanks again man you really helped me out!!

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
$time = time();

foreach (range(0, 12) as $i)
{
    echo '<option value="' . date('Y-m', $time) . '">' . $month[date('m', $time)] . date('y', $time) . '</option>' . "\n";

    if ($i >= 1)
    {
        $time = strtotime('next month', $time);
    }
}
```